# Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have the following situation.

I am trying to insert a new Object of type Category.
Category inherits from a class Entity which I created. When I try to create or update a Category. The SaveChanges of the context fails.

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AspNetUsers'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetUsers'

Here you can see the class Entity.

```
public class Entity : IEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
    public StateCode StateCode { get; set; }

    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I also have a class User who inherits from IdentityUser

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

All my other entities have the base class "Entity".
I made an override for the SaveChanges that will set the CreatedOn, CreatedBy, ... on Save.

```
        var user = GetLoggedInUser();

        base.ChangeTracker.Entries().ToList().ForEach(e =>
        {
            if (e.Entity.GetType() != typeof(User))
            {
                switch (e.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        ((Entity)e.Entity).Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                        ((Entity)e.Entity).CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                        ((Entity)e.Entity).ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
                        ((Entity)e.Entity).CreatedBy = user;
                        ((Entity)e.Entity).ModifiedBy = user;
                        break;
                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        ((Entity)e.Entity).ModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
                        ((Entity)e.Entity).ModifiedBy = user;
                        break;
                }
            }

        });
```

When I call Context.SaveChanges(); I get this error. 
I don't understand why it's trying to create the user, when it already exists? I am retrieving the user in GetLoggedInUser().

Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: Are you using the same context to retrieve the user?

Comment: Yes I am using the same context.

Comment: How does the class look where you want to save your edits

Comment: Everything is filled in correctly. Including the existing user.

Comment: I added this to the line under the retrieve of the user.
this.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Unchanged; This seems to work but probably give me problems in the future.